# How can I get the 'Trying Anything Once' achievement in Just Cause 2?

Tags: just-cause-2

I am trying to achieve "*Trying Anything Once: Drive all 104 vehicles*" in `Just Cause 2`.

I almost reached 75 vehicles but I miss about 30 now. Where can I find a list of all vehicles type and the area in which they can be found?

And additionally, is it possible to understand which are the vehicles I already driven, because I am not sure I remember all of them?

Comment: Something to note is the fact that the DLC vehicles count towards the total. So make sure you have bought them at least once and hopped in. It makes hunting down the rarer vehicles a tiny bit easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a comprehensive list on the Just Cause 2 [wikia](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Just_Cause_2_Vehicles) with hints on where to find them...

Answer (score 8):

The Just Cause wiki, now has [a list of vehicles and their locations now](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Just_Cause_2_Vehicles).

In the menu of the game, there is a Database option and under there is a Vehicle listing which marks which ones you've driven.

Comment: The PC version has the database vehicle listing too.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that site is going to be closed.